# TextEdit disappears on keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.85"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="10px">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="299dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:lines="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clear" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.52" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong with that layout?

1) when I open the app in portrait mode this TextEdit is visible until I click it in order to enter some text (there is only blackness). If I than turn it into landscape mode the textedit appears again (in full screen mode)

2) when I open the app in landscape mode there is only layout header and the blackness below again.

It doesn't seem too complex..
Here is the pseudo-xml:

```
<row>
  <col. for text>
  <col. for button>
</row>
<row>
  <some text here>
</row>
```

Can you help me fix this layout or give me some better example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a listview with a height of 413dp (pretty huge). I think you misunderstand that layout_weight determines how to assign *excess* space, of which there's not going to be very much given your listview is so big.

What you probably want is to set your horizontal linearlayout to have no layout_weight and tell the listview to use it all:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
</ListView>
```